# Is the sum of two Gaussian functions a Gaussian?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

If $f(x) = e^{-a x^2}$ and $g(x) = e^{-b x^2}$ with $a, b > 0$, does there exist a pair of positive numbers $(A, c)$ such that the equation

$$A e^{-cx^2} = f(x) + g(x) $$
is satisfied? I tried Gaussian integration but it does not seem to work. I am actually looking for the answer to the more general question:

Let $\vec \xi = \left[x_1 \ x_2 \ ...  \ x_n \right]^T$ be an $n$ dimensional vector. Suppose we have two Gaussian functions: $$f(\vec \xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathrm{det}A}} \exp(\vec \xi^T A^{-1}\vec \xi),$$ and $$g(\vec \xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathrm{det}B}} \exp(\vec \xi^T B^{-1}\vec \xi),$$ where $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$ symmetric and positive definite matrices.

If $k (\vec \xi) = f (\vec \xi) + g (\vec \xi)$, can we find a matrix $C$ (with the same properties) such that $$k(\vec \xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathrm{det}C}} \exp(\vec \xi^T C^{-1}\vec \xi)$$

Comment: Please let me know if there is a more appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: are you trying to talk about the random variables described by that distribution function? because the way you've written it, you're just summing the distribution functions, and it's obviously false

Comment: @ZoeAllen I am not talking about the random variables, I'm just summing the functions. Why is it false?

Comment: In the one dimensional case, any gaussians with different coefficient will behave differently asymptotically. So for the gaussian with the c coefficient to behave the same asymptotically as the sum, c would have to be the same as the smaller of a and b. But obviously that doesn't work when a and b are different. In the n dimensional case you can do the same thing with limiting to infinity in a particular direction.

Comment: Take derivatives of both sides. You get that this is impossible unless $a = b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible unless $a=b$. Suppose you can find such $A$ and $c$. From the behavior at infinity, if $a<b$, you need $c=a$. But then if you write
$$
Ae^{-cx^2}=e^{-ax^2}+e^{-bx^2}
$$
and you divide both sides by $e^{-ax^2}=e^{-cx^2}$ and take the limit at $\infty$, you conclude $A=1$ necessarily. After cancellation, you get $e^{-ax^2}=0$ identically, which is impossible.